# Breaking up an XML file

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing

I've got an XML output that produces code such as:

```
<loadavg>
   <one>0.00</one>
   <five>0.02</five>
   <fifteen>0.02</fifteen>
</loadavg>
<!-- whostmgrd -->
```

I would like to know how I can use PHP to parse that file, and grab the contents between `<one>`,`<five>` and `<fifteen>`. It would be useful if it were to be stored as `$loadavg[1]` an array.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) can do it:

```
$xml = <<<XML
    <loadavg>
        <one>0.00</one>
        <five>0.02</five> 
        <fifteen>0.02</fifteen>
    </loadavg>
XML;

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$loadavg = array((string) $root->one, 
                 (string) $root->five, 
                 (string) $root->fifteen);

print_r($loadavg);
```

prints

```
Array (
   [0] => 0.00
   [1] => 0.02
   [2] => 0.02 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to parse an XML file is using [SimpleXML](http://ca.php.net/Simplexml). It should be easy to load the XML as a SimpleXML object and get the data using that. If you could post a sample of a complete XML file I could offer some sample code.